# trying to call selectize with different parameter, but it runs with old value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selectize.js

I have a function which receives a parameter and then calls [selectize.js][1].

Initially I call `myFunc` with `param` equal 1. It works, the data comes from server, and I get a dropdown list with it.

But later I call `myFunc` with another `param` value, let's say 2.

And I see in the console, that `myFunc` receives 2, but `load` function and ajax `success` function log 1 to console, and data comes as if `param` value was 1.

If I call `myFunc` with `param` equals 2 first time, the data comes as if `param` value is 2.

I tried to add to both `load` and ajax `success` function `cache: false`. But `load` function continues to use old `param` value.

```
function myFunc(param) {
    console.log(param);
    $("#select-control").selectize({
        valueField: 'id',
        labelField: 'name',
        searchField: 'name',
        options: [],
        create: false,
        render: {
            option: function(item, escape) {
                return '<div>' + escape(item.name) + '</div>';
            }
        },
        score: function(search) {
            return function(item) {
                return 1;
            }
        },
        load: function (query, callback) {
            console.log("selectize loading data");
            console.log(param);
            this.clearOptions();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/some/end/point",
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    q: query,
                    some_param: param
                },
                error: function () {
                    callback();
                },
                success: function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                    console.log(param);
                    callback(JSON.parse(res));
                },
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Here is edited log from the console

```
23378 // myFunc received this value as param
selectize loading data // load function is called
23378 // param value inside load function
{/* here is the response, which contains data */}
23378 // param value inside ajax success function
19476 // myFunc received new value
selectize loading data // load function is called
23378 // but the load function uses the first param value, it should be 19476 here
{/* the same old response, param didn't change*/}
23378 // and ajax success function also uses the old value, it also should be 19476
```

Comment: Can you put a print screen of all the logs please? If I am correct in thinking, its impossible that the first `console` will output something different from the `console` inside the load function

Comment: just posted values from console. The first time you're right, first `console` doesn't output something different, but when calling `myFunc` second time it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added global variable for `param` and then I use it.

```
var globalParam;

function myFunc(param) {
    globalParam = param;

    // ...
    /* use globalParam instead of param later*/
    // ...
}
```

I don't know why it didn't work without global variable